# C# EF Core LINQ simple join

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework-core

I am more used to manual sql query but I have to admit that EF core context & model is more convenient knowing I don't need to open and close database manually. All set upon new. But I really have no idea how a very simple LINQ query which I think resemble sql query, return an error with fieldname that is not even on any of my models.

```
[Index(nameof(Name), IsUnique = true)]
internal class modelLibraryCustomer
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Additional { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}

[Index(nameof(IdSubProduct), nameof(EffectiveDate), IsUnique = true)]
internal class modelDataProductSubProductRate
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string IdSubProduct { get; set; }
    public string? IdCustomer { get; set; }
    public DateOnly EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    public string Additional { get; set; }

    public virtual modelLibraryCustomer Name { get; set; }
}


var query = (from rm in this.contextSQL.ProductSubProductRate
             join c in this.contextSQL.LibraryCustomer on rm.IdCustomer equals c.Id
             select new { rm.Id, rm.Name, rm.Rate }).ToList();
this.contextSQL.ProductSubProductRate.Load();
```

MySqlConnector.MySqlException: 'Unknown column 'p.NameId' in 'on clause''

Not a single column in my model / database contain NameId.

Comment: Ensure that database is on sync with EF Core model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell EF Core what the foreign key is to the `modelLibraryCustomer` table. By convention it is looking for `NameId` which doesn't exist. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/conventions#discovering-foreign-key-properties

Assuming `IdCustomer` is the foreign key, you need to inform the model of this which can be done with attributes:

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(IdCustomer)]
public virtual modelLibraryCustomer Name { get; set; }
```